# I want to use imgareaselect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, img-area-select-jquery

I m new in jquery.and my new task is "imgareaselect in jquery".
I am refering [THIS](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/).
but i am lacking somewhere to understand the logic.
pls help me to create "imgareaselect"

Now my coading is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js">     </script>
      <script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img id="photo" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <script>
          $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
            handles: true,
            onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
             alert('width: ' + selection.width + '; height: ' + selection.height);
           }
         });
        </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Any code? have you tried something?

Comment: actually i m not able to prepare html code for this ...1: download plugin  then 2:link in head section.  3:script function. now ?.....

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It's pretty straightforward, to have the data load in the input boxes takes more work though.

Comment: whatever id given in script, give that id to image element in html. please go through documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML w/ JAVASCRIPT**

```
...
<head>
<script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <img id="photo" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />

    <script>
    $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
            alert('width: ' + selection.width + '; height: ' + selection.height);
        }
    });
    </script>

</body>
...
```

Try it out and experiment on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HK2gu/).  Read the documentation and you can see the limitations.

Comment: I edit my question please review it.

Comment: It should be noted that the `<script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css"></script>` is referencing a Cascading Stylesheet and should be referenced by `<link href="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css" type="stylesheet">` instead.