# imgAreaSelect is storing all previous selection of coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, imageareaselect

Unable to clean old data 'selection' while using imgAreaSelect in jQuery

```
$('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
    handles: true,
    onSelectEnd: someFunction
});


alert('x=' + selection.x1 + ' y=' + selection.y1 + ' x2=' + selection.x2 + ' y2=' + selection.y2)
```

On running above code multiple times on same image with different region of interest selection. The selection co-ordinates doesn't clear old values and on publishing its showing alert windows with each set.

Please suggest the ways to clear old values

Comment: you can check the below answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536441/i-want-to-use-imgareaselect-in-jquery)

Comment: My problem is different, I am able to implement imgAreaSelect successfully, but when multiple markings (x1, x2, y1,y2) are getting recorded, its not clearing up old data and that's messing up my final image